# PC is struggling with uploads/downloads on multiple web browsers

Tags: networking, performance, download, upload

Running on gigabit internet, Windows 10 (Build 19044), Core i5-9600KF, 64GB RAM, 2070 SUPER, 1TB m.2. I run CCleaner and BitDefender on this thing somewhat often to keep it tidy, and out of nowhere my PC started having this issue where uploading and downloading files over the internet (email, cloud storage, etc.) basically stopped working.  Gmail website will load up and immediately tell me that I'm offline; YouTube videos are stuck at 0% upload; anything I try to download from cloud storage takes multiple attempts of me refreshing the page and very quickly navigating to the file I want to download and spamming the download link.  Streaming platforms like HBOMax/Netflix/Discovery+/YouTube spend a few minutes buffering just to play a few seconds of 480p quality before giving me a network error. But gaming on my machine is still as great as the day I built it; low ping and smooth FPS.

Internet speed tests indicate that all ISP hardware is functioning properly, which I believe is accurate because I can do all of those things listed above on my older laptop just fine.

Some things I have tried to address the issue:

- Checked Windows Security to make sure P2P functions are off (not that anyone else is on my home network)
- Tried multiple browsers (Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge)
- Cleared caches that were pretty much already clear
- Removed the one Chrome browser plugin I had but never used (Honey)
- Checked for driver updates (CCleaner Pro does that for me, but I checked manually anyways)

I would hate to do a fresh Windows install.  Has anyone encountered a similar issue and know a fix for what I suspect to be a windows settings issue?

Comment: Use Windows Defender to scan for malware.   Also run TCP/IP Reset.   Restart after doing these things.  …. Netsh ip reset  c:\resetlog.txt

Comment: also, don't hesitate to engage with your ISP.  just because a speed test works doesn't mean there isn't a problem upstream from you (like billing code issues or somesuch).

Comment: To add to the list of things I've attempted:

Ran TCP/IP Reset and DNS Flush; ran DISM (dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth; and SFC /SCANNOW.  Still no improvement in performance, unfortunately.

Comment: Also, if this were a problem with my ISP, wouldn't all the devices connected to my router have the same issue?  My old gaming laptop and both of my work computers work just fine.